# ¿En qué estoy fallando con estas líneas de code?

Tags: php

me gustaría hacer y/o mostrar un archivo dependiendo del user-agent que acceda a mi página web, he hecho las siguiente líneas de código pero sin embargo estoy observando que cambia el user-agent del browser al que yo le ponga. Dejo aquí el code:

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
if ($user_agent = "caca") {


print "$user_agent";
}
else{
    header("Location: https://google.es/");
}
```

Comment: Cuando se comparan valores se debe usar [el operador `===`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php), al momento en tu código lo que estás haciendo es asignar el texto a `$user_agent`

Comment: El comparendo debe ser == o === de otro modo, solo estas asignando "caca" a la variable

Comment: Además no veo por que poner entre comillas a `$user_agent` al momento de imprimir su contenido cuando de hecho no vas a agregar algún string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás asignando el valor al `$user_agent` con el signo `=` en lugar de compararlo con `==`

```php
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
    if ($user_agent == "caca") {


    print "$user_agent";
    }
    else{
        header("Location: https://google.es/");
    }
```

Documentación relacionada [Link 1](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.php) y [Link 2](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php).